# WooCommerce quantity for different products only - header mini cart - count(WC()->cart->get_cart())

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, spinner, cart

Having problem implementing changes for the total quantity of products in the header mini cart.

Currently woocommerce calculate total qty for all products in cart:

```
echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
```

We need a solution which will calculate qty for different products only. So we have modified code:

```
echo count(WC()->cart->get_cart());
```

That is working fine, qty is shown show by different products only, but now we have AJAX bug,
spinner keep loading and page need a manual refresh. After refresh products are successfully added to cart and mini cart is updated with new product qty calc.

What could be a problem with stopping AJAX from working properly?

Comment: Did you dig into javascript console?

Comment: No errors found  in console.  Ty

Comment: Was able to solve this one    by adding a hook callback to target 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count'  filter.  Posting the answer atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with different approach by adding a hook callback. Working perfectly.

```
 /**
 * @snippet     WC Mini Cart / Product Quantity Calculation by Unique Products - Excluding the same products 
 * @author      Rkoms
**/

// define the woocommerce_cart_contents_count callback 
function filter_woocommerce_cart_contents_count($unique_product_qty) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    $unique_product_qty = count(WC()->cart->get_cart());
    return $unique_product_qty; 
};          
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_contents_count', 15, 1 );
```